# Note taking app with Rich Text Editor (RTE) and cloud sync

Tags: software-recommendation, fonts, sync, notes

I am recently migrated to Linux systems. While I get most of software alternatives I miss OneNote and Evernote kind of note taking apps. I found many open source apps but none of them having rich text editing (RTE). For example:

Joplin: It is one of the best apps but its RTE is restricted as markdown is actual scheme. Text color, font shape, size not easily available.

Obsidian: Also like Joplin and one of best but still markdown not RTE.

Zoho Notebook: While it is beautiful. It lacks text color, linux app lacks font size (android and windows do).

Simple Note: Lacks RTE.

Standard Notes: RTE is paid. Free version allows only plain text. No image, highlights etc.

Zettlr: It is with very aesthetic look and feel. Markdown no RTE.

Trillium: Hierarchical structure. Markdown. No RTE.

Yana: Excellent RTE. But no cloud sync only local workspace.

TagSpaces: Good HTML editor but hard time getting sync.

Of all surveyed Joplin is best till now. Easy dropbox, onedrive sync. Does Linux has any note app that supports RTE and cloud sync? Please suggest.

Comment: "Evernote works on all your devices"

Comment: Yes but has device restriction.

Comment: I was looking for a similar tool. RTF is really great because text coloring works  great (unlike in Markdown). Unfortunately, there are no many apps in the Ubuntu world that support rtf.